# How to check whether CAN bus controller's drivers are presented in my Debian Wheezy?

Tags: debian

I've heard that Linux kernel has native CAN bus support at network layer since some years, with a lot of drivers for both embedded and USB CAN bus controllers, how do I check whether they are presented in my Debian Wheezy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for `/boot/config<...>` file (belongs to kernel deb package).  CAN support is enabled in Wheezy:

```
CONFIG_CAN=m
CONFIG_CAN_RAW=m
CONFIG_CAN_BCM=m
CONFIG_CAN_GW=m

#
# CAN Device Drivers
#
CONFIG_CAN_VCAN=m
CONFIG_CAN_SLCAN=m
CONFIG_CAN_DEV=m
CONFIG_CAN_CALC_BITTIMING=y
CONFIG_CAN_MCP251X=m
CONFIG_PCH_CAN=m
CONFIG_CAN_SJA1000=m
# CONFIG_CAN_SJA1000_PLATFORM is not set
CONFIG_CAN_EMS_PCMCIA=m
CONFIG_CAN_EMS_PCI=m
CONFIG_CAN_PEAK_PCI=m
CONFIG_CAN_KVASER_PCI=m
CONFIG_CAN_PLX_PCI=m
# CONFIG_CAN_C_CAN is not set

#
# CAN USB interfaces
#
CONFIG_CAN_EMS_USB=m
CONFIG_CAN_ESD_USB2=m
CONFIG_CAN_SOFTING=m
CONFIG_CAN_SOFTING_CS=m
# CONFIG_CAN_DEBUG_DEVICES is not set
```